# Big noise from Power Supply Unity Fa? Should I replace it immediately?

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer

Recently, I started to get a large noise from my PC when switched on. After some time, it disappears. I discovered that the issue is with the Power Supply Unit. Does this mean I have a failing PSU? Will it harm the PC if I didn't replace it immediately?

Several years ago I bought a new computer casing which is very weird. Its small and compact. Normally, we have the PSU in the top. But in here, the PSU is on the bottom and right below the hard drive. Recently, two of my hard drives started to show problems. Read errors and bad sectors. Can it be the PSU and the design of the casing?

Here's an image of the PSU and the hard drive :

[image: Here's an image of the PSU and the hard drive :]

Comment: Is it a jet enginish *whosh* or a "ladaladalada" like something is loose inside?

Comment: Its like 'broooooooom'. A loud noice

Comment: sounds like dust problems

Comment: @Sathya surely the broooom is what would sort out the dust   ha ha  :)

Comment: This question is nearly a duplicate of your other questions, please take the time to write the question clearly instead of just copying and pasting another question and changing one line as your questions are identical in other of your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is so hard to answer but, if you computer is old, then it's a chance it is failing (and if you replace one part of all could be the bigger question).

Can the PSU cause problems - well, yes, if it spikes. Is this going to happen - I can't tell. I've had many PC's and looked after many PC's in jobs and have experienced it once (during a powercut).